# How to introduce NAs conditioned to lacking combination of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have the following dataset

```
structure(list(f = c("3", "4", "6", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "23", "24", "27", 
"29", "30", "32", "46", "48", "51", "3", "4", "8", "9", "10"), 
    m = c("opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", 
    "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", 
    "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", 
    "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", "opono", 
    "opono", "opono", "opono"), q = c("low", "low", "low", "low", 
    "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", 
    "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", "low", 
    "low", "low", "low", "high", "high", "high", "high", "high"
    ), w = c("side", "side", "side", "side", "side", "side", 
    "side", "side", "side", "side", "side", "side", "side", "side", 
    "side", "side", "side", "side", "side", "side", "side", "side", 
    "side", "side", "side", "side", "side", "side", "side", "side"
    ), VAR1 = c(561.089399192576, 581.548488568111, 567.717424054861, 
    572.499819619073, 578.418615535074, 570.941802587348, 576.295269720571, 
    578.007467895353, 576.948882739012, 565.643167588304, 573.256137379379, 
    575.034045688634, 568.331521335574, 572.389567966884, 568.183592008537, 
    569.067750762838, 567.136620939278, 572.677977963927, 565.559529436895, 
    571.348256516843, 568.488661937201, 565.256601794686, 568.769028477292, 
    566.473773134573, 566.876164738997, 569.847746252395, 576.898378005246, 
    568.263805959133, 568.498927341304, 570.809708096595), VAR2 = c(566.829488261267, 
    583.422840017742, 569.673626181696, 573.849025919752, 580.827499613903, 
    571.504854495285, 580.350506032764, 579.390897780772, 578.69338358936, 
    570.904584986574, 575.052971086715, 574.688248425541, 570.733574343438, 
    574.857082758917, 571.787080177344, 571.569171923806, 570.838097106968, 
    575.255589230351, 566.940421687024, 572.439099190377, 570.351971362338, 
    568.882657086159, 570.264671773197, 567.354301906239, 570.808400776722, 
    576.573717673962, 578.66154755034, 570.332191431051, 572.95393469287, 
    572.083632292557), VAR3 = c(572.074153197824, 582.339853113654, 
    573.526048019733, 577.463827648692, 580.873568765641, 572.885325776466, 
    581.510222223467, 579.519045748115, 578.671113004724, 576.951307378829, 
    575.310949187926, 573.991781008638, 571.170978283022, 575.672012100918, 
    573.66776618585, 575.225328918342, 575.406888307793, 573.310938901297, 
    566.464161127989, 572.29797857409, 571.370713183438, 572.510797167114, 
    572.526903797217, 567.487468513351, 573.025793789199, 583.051110888242, 
    580.339193348831, 574.940170801097, 576.096595238378, 573.452900233279
    ), VAR4 = c(569.664181971811, 575.104257647447, 569.925567749676, 
    567.169290903345, 574.204696551093, 568.9856544863, 569.97215353084, 
    574.005126512475, 573.707139791972, 569.088814356572, 571.459320801408, 
    571.20375043148, 566.896031834279, 570.678180552085, 566.776933610229, 
    570.998846618514, 570.140354957222, 572.47287147126, 566.780774126067, 
    570.943707461063, 565.284896788255, 568.136872567246, 566.29200349809, 
    565.590742078695, 570.788632197349, 569.628730897358, 571.050976347298, 
    563.725161715263, 566.429831807809, 570.177573295053), VAR5 = c(572.132317217948, 
    575.338599386577, 570.280728618934, 567.297485431633, 574.064517225767, 
    567.972475549039, 574.284231232552, 573.42883810891, 571.999943227003, 
    570.965234552693, 570.07870043507, 569.625491010925, 567.457886313675, 
    570.780061117808, 569.797732457914, 572.211977633002, 571.034286441696, 
    573.395672804264, 566.653342692837, 569.712501203962, 565.680441987346, 
    568.656899188585, 565.450351401852, 565.136306681055, 572.589873330853, 
    570.738647188268, 571.999025966806, 566.076177642574, 567.521260887323, 
    571.23743123055), VAR6 = c(574.115841254771, 574.187428289689, 
    572.101721511176, 569.059690853244, 573.092059511665, 566.187723603179, 
    573.216416465856, 574.108779980335, 571.469210777496, 573.272507607687, 
    569.660498508474, 569.234718236738, 567.343480327257, 569.515269462058, 
    569.501406083879, 573.302584862076, 571.896776926826, 570.341708427438, 
    566.353252074126, 569.149369502107, 565.006447340628, 570.113275902549, 
    564.44459129395, 564.143689984709, 571.035375694453, 572.838042674364, 
    572.714248131889, 569.424270838823, 569.824528704453, 571.675890154353
    )), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I should enter NAs conditioned to lacking combinations of character levels `q`, `f` and `w`. I have started created this grid

```
  f = unique(dt$f)
  q = unique(dt$q)
  w = unique(dt$w)

grid = expand.grid(f, q, w) %>% 
  mutate(m = NA, 
         VAR1 = NA, 
         VAR2 = NA,  
         VAR3 = NA, 
         VAR4 = NA, 
         VAR5 = NA, 
         VAR6 = NA)
```

if the combination `w, f and q` is lacking in the original dataset it should keep for the `range VAR1:VAR6` the same values present in it. Otherwise, those rows should have NAs.

I have tried different methods with `merge and left_join` but they did not work. Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: what is your expected outcome?

Comment: Not sure what the expected output it but 
would `dt %>% tidyr::complete(f, q, w)` work?